# Unable to rebind the values of controls in MVC partial view

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, partial-views, ajaxform

Below is the AJAX call that i am using to render a partial view

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/apps/Applications',
    dataType: 'html',
    contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8',
    type: 'post',
    data: $('#TaskList').serialize()
    //data: $('#form_' + id).serialize()
    //data: { appID: ID }
}).success(function (result) {
    $('#OpenApplications').show().append('<div class="tab-pane active" id="subnav_' + id + '" >' + result + '</div>');
}).error(function (xhr, status) {
    alert(status);
});
```

And my partialview has control as

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Application.ID, new { id = "appid"})
```

I am getting the value of `Application.ID` in the backend, but in front end the value is not binding to the control of `application.ID`.

below is the controller code

```
        data.TaskChanges = new TaskHistory(data.Application.ID, data.Application.InternalStatus, data.Application.Processor, data.Application.AssessorComments, data.Application.InternalNotes);
        // we create if empty
        if (data.OpenTasks == null)
        {
            data.OpenTasks = new Dictionary<int, string>();
        }
        // now we add if not present
        if (!data.OpenTasks.ContainsKey(data.Application.ID))
        {
            data.OpenTasks.Add(data.Application.ID, data.Application.PID);
        }

        return PartialView("OpenApplications", data);
```

Any help?

Comment: Can you show your controller code too??

Comment: added controller code

Comment: There is no need to set `value` attribute in your `TextBoxFor`

Comment: Try this `@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Application.ID, new { id = "appid")`

Comment: Even if you dont set it, it is not working, Updated the partial view code.

Comment: everything seems right, what is the `result ` of ajax success?

Comment: It is like <input type="number" id="Application_ID" value="" /> which should not be the case. My requirement is to populate the Application.ID value in it. It should be like <input type="number" id="Application_ID" value="56" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using below line in controller method

ModelState.Clear();